# Angular assets works only on localhost

Tags: angular

I have problem with serving Angular app on custom host. In my case I'm using:

```
ng serve --host 192.168.1.14 --disable-host-check --ssl true --ssl-cert ./192.168.1.14.pem --ssl-key ./192.168.1.14-key.pem
```

to serve my app with SSL and make it accessible in my local network.

App is working fine, I'm able to access it on https://192.168.1.14:PORT via my mobile phone, but anything from /assets folder isn't loading. Both on desktop or mobile. In my desktop console I'm receiving this error:

```
ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/pl.json', ok: false, …}
```

As you can see, default host is still localhost:4200 not 192.168.1.14:4200.

Do you know solution to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using `ng server` to server your angular app in a production environment, you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: No, It's just for development purposes. I need to check some of mobile features: camera, geolocation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out. The problem was not in my Angular configuration but in TranslateService - path to files was not relative.

Cheers.